# Does Weapon Plant and Outfit Factory give exp?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Does anyone know if the Weapon Plant or Outfit Factory give experience (besides incidents of course)?

I want to produce +7E outfits and send my SPECIAL maxed level 1 dwellers into the wasteland, and max out their HP. However, I first need to produce these outfits.

Not having enough dwellers yet to go around, my idea was to use these maxed out level 1 guys to make their own clothes - but I can't have them leveling in this room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but they need to be working on it! The rooms change the s.p.e.c.i.a.l depends you do, for example, if the outfit factory are doing a shirt with skill A it would be nice if you drag and drop a pj with skill A, and etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but only when they are being productive - I.e. when they are crafting something.